# Unable to right-click my Windows icon on the taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, right-click

For some reason I'm no longer able to right-click my Windows icon. Normally I would use it as a shortcut to quickly Shutdown or Restart my computer, but now it requires two extra clicks.

- All other taskbar icons (programs, etc.) function normally.
- I've already tried restarting my File Explorer in the Task Manager

In the gif below you can also see that the cursor moves up/right every time I right-click, which is very strange.
[image]

Comment: this regedit may be relevant: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-right-click-on-start-menu-items-in/fb1fd0d0-1188-4e0d-b78a-265e7943dd1d

Comment: @mael' sounds like a perfect answer to me. Why not write it out? I'd vote it up if done properly (eg: not an answer with a link to that article, but actually copy/pasting it to preserve the data)

Comment: @LPChip you have fueled the procrastination fire that is my superuser participation

Comment: I love the addition of the gif - I never realized the mouse behaves that way when you right-click the Windows/Start icon - even when it's behaving normally (mine does the same thing).

Comment: added a couple more things to try to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following these steps:

> - Launch the Registry Editor as an administrator
> - Navigate to the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ ImmersiveShell\Launcher
> - Click Edit
> - Click New
> - Select DWORD (32-bit) Value
> - Name it UseExperience.
> - Double-click the newly created item and set the value to 0.
> - Click OK
> - Close the Registry Editor and then restart your computer -- or just restart Explorer.

If that doesn't work, you may also try running Powershell as administrator with the following commands:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

There may be some errors you can ignore, but when it finishes it should be working... but if it's still not, there is a folder that may be corrupted or missing in your user profile:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX
```

If you have access to a different machine that's not having issues, you should be able to copy the entire WinX folder into yours and see if that corrects the problem. If you don't have access to a different machine, there's a possibility that you can just create another user profile on your machine, see if your right-click is working there, and copy that folder over if it is.

References: [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-right-click-on-start-menu-items-in/fb1fd0d0-1188-4e0d-b78a-265e7943dd1d), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f2ren/cant_use_start_menu_or_right_click_taskbar_icons/ctkwo5x/), [techmesto](https://www.techmesto.com/fix-start-menu-broken-windows-10-technical-preview/), and [urtech](https://www.urtech.ca/2014/04/solved-when-i-right-click-the-start-button-nothing-happens-in-windows-8-1/).

Comment: +1 from me. Well done. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick answer. I've tried both solutions but there is no difference :/

Comment: Sorry it's still giving you trouble, I've found an additional powershell line that may help you (added to my answer); try running them in the order they are listed. I'll keep looking as well; it could also be a shell issue as described here by a person with a slightly different issue (fix action requires third-party software if you're open to that): https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/101286-right-clicking-start-menu-items-not-working.html

Comment: You're the man @mael'! I created a different user on my computer and copied the folders from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` to my main account and restarted my computer. My start menu now behaves normally again! Unfortunately I can never unsee the cursor behavior when right-clicking the start menu, haha! Thank you so much for your time and persistence!

Comment: happy to help! was an interesting issue

Comment: I joined the community just to give you a thumbs up! it fixed after the powershell script

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed the winx folder from my laptop and imported it directly on my pc replacing the old winx which was empty for me and it solved the issue.

Did the registry editor step and the powershell steps and i removed the previous updates but nothing solved it.

Im just gonna assume changing the winx was the significant benefactor.

Thank you for the information!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1132747)